# ¿Como seleccionar últimos 4 meses de un campo Date de diferentes llaves foráneas en la misma tabla SQL Server?

Tags: sql, asp.net

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada Costo:

```
int     int   decimal   decimal    Date          int            bool
Id     Monto    Iva      Total     Fecha    IdConsultoria    Entregado
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 0      1000     160      1160      1/1/16        1             true  
 1      2000     280      2280      1/2/16        1             true 
 2      3000     480      3480      1/3/16        1             false
 3      4000     640      4640      1/4/16        1             false
 4      4000     640      4640      1/5/16        1             false
 5      4000     640      4640      1/6/16        1             false
 6      4000     640      4640      1/7/16        1             false
 7      1000     160      1160      1/1/16        2             true 
 8      1000     160      1160      1/2/16        2             true 
 9      1000     160      1160      1/3/16        2             true 
10      1000     160      1160      1/4/16        2             true  
11      2000     280      2280      1/5/16        2             true 
12      3000     480      3480      1/6/16        2             true
13      4000     640      4640      1/7/16        2             false
14      1000     160      1160      1/8/16        2             true 
15      1000     160      1160      1/1/16        3             true 
16      1000     160      1160      1/2/16        3             true 
17      1000     160      1160      1/3/16        3             true  
18      2000     280      2280      1/4/16        3             true 
19      3000     480      3480      1/5/16        3             true
```

Necesito traer todos los registros de la tabla Costo pero solo los últimos 4 meses de cada IdConsultoria que es una llave foránea de la tabla Consultoria en la que solo tiene los campos: Id, Nombre, CantidadEmpleados y Contacto pero de esta tabla no necesito traer nada.

Necesito esta salida.

```
  Id     Monto    Iva      Total     Fecha    IdConsultoria    Entregado
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   3      4000     640      4640      1/4/16        1             false
   4      4000     640      4640      1/5/16        1             false
   5      4000     640      4640      1/6/16        1             false
   6      4000     640      4640      1/7/16        1             false
  11      2000     280      2280      1/5/16        2             true  
  12      3000     480      3480      1/6/16        2             true 
  13      4000     640      4640      1/7/16        2             false
  14      1000     160      1160      1/8/16        2             true 
  16      1000     160      1160      1/2/16        3             true  
  17      1000     160      1160      1/3/16        3             true 
  18      2000     280      2280      1/4/16        3             true
  19      3000     480      3480      1/5/16        3             true
```

Comment: Buen día Abraham, bienvenido a StackOverflow. De tu redacción no me queda muy claro lo que quieres decir con **los últimos 4 meses de cada IdConsultoria**, sugiero que si las respuestas actuales no son correctas y ya que tenemos los datos de entrada, coloques un ejemplo de la salida que quieres obtener. Así será más fácil darte una respuesta.

Comment: Ok, actualizo mi post

Comment: ya lo edite como debe de ser, GRACIAS!

Answer (score 1):

*Editado*

Me parece que con algo así bastaría.

```
SELECT Id, Monto, Iva, Total, Fecha, IdConsultoria, Entregado FROM Costo
WHERE Fecha >= DATEADD(month, -4, GETDATE()) -- Esto le resta 4 meses a la fecha actual
ORDER BY IdConsultoria asc, Fecha asc;
```

Comment: Ya lo edite, me puedes ayudar

Comment: Listo, algo así?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba una consulta similar a la siguiente:

```
SELECT Id, Monto, Iva, Total, Fecha, IdConsultoria, Entregado
FROM Costo
WHERE Fecha <= DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE());
ORDER BY IdConsultoria, Fecha -- por defecto, está organizado de manera ascendente (ASC).
```

Comment: La edición quedo lista de lo que necesito.

Comment: @AbrahamRivera, he actualizado la respuesta, ejecuta la instrucción SQL y verifica si los resultados coinciden con lo esperado. Usa [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) para elaborar un ejemplo funcional con el que podamos probar. La respuesta de Daniel Sánchez también me parece correcta.

Comment: Esto en realidad traería los datos de enero a abril de cualquier año, no los de los últimos 4 meses!

Comment: @jachguate, correcto, he editado mi respuesta, aunque admito que es similar a la del usuario "Dan". Dejo al criterio del OP si hace seguimiento de su pregunta.